# KendoUI Programmatically get/change Note visual in Chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

In this example, I can successfully change the properties/style of a Note on Chart on noteClick... http://dojo.telerik.com/@pagemedias/oVuWI

What I need to do is 'trigger' this from outside the Chart.

**Example:** I am outputting the same list of Notes that appear on the chart under the chart and when user clicks/hovers over note under chart I want to change colour/style of same Note in chart.

I have been able to highlight note under chart (has css class of 'key-A') when click on note in chart (get noteText which = 'A' and add a new styling class to 'key-A' under chart). But I also want to achieve the same thing, just the other way around (click note under chart and highlight note in chart).

*​How do I access e.visual of a particular note in chart?*

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to do it with the KendoUI chart API; however, you can do it by manipulating the chert svg elements directly.

As you can't assign a class to the notes, set the opacity of the note text to 0.99999 so you can use it as a selector:

```
var text = new kendo.drawing.Text(e.text,[targetPoint.x-4,targetPoint.y-23],{font: "bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif",cursor: "pointer", opacity: 0.99999});
```

Then when you click your list item outside the chart, you can get all the note text nodes with this selector:

```
var notes = $('.k-chart text[opacity="0.99999"]');
```

Then iterate through the notes to find the one with matching text, change the color, find the image node and change the source:

```
notes.each(function(idx){
  if ($(this).text() == noteText){
        this.fill = "#ff0000";
        this.style.fill = "#ff0000";
        var img = $(this).prev('image');
        img.attr('xlink:href','http://www.appointmentreminder.com.au/images/v3/svg/other/greenicon/message.svg');
  }
});
```